# Rendering a textbox for a complex type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have been reading the various blog posts on how to deal with a Complex Type in EF including the brad wilson post which most everyone seems to link. owever i dont really get it. I am using EF code first development, MVC and VB. From what i have read so far to render a editor field for a complex types requires a custom object, right? However i dont really understand what code i need to put into the custom template. Can someone break it down for me as to what code needs to go into custom templete so i can render a textbox for the PostTags icollection?

My classes:

```
 Public Class Post
    Inherits EntityBase

    <Key()> Property PostId As Integer
    <DisplayName("Title")> <Required()> Property PostTitle As String
    <UIHint("MultilineText")> <DisplayName("Text")> Property PostText As String

    ReadOnly Property PostExcerpt As String
        Get
            If PostText.Length > 100 Then
                Return Helpers.TruncateHelper.TruncateAtWord(PostText, 250)
            Else : Return PostText
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> Property PostDateCreated As DateTime
    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> Property PostDateModified As DateTime?
    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> Property PostDatePublished As DateTime?

    <DisplayName("Publish?")> Property PostIsPublished As Boolean
    <DisplayName("Allow Comments?")> Property CommentsAllowed As Boolean
    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> Property CategoryId As Integer?
    <UIHint("Text")> <DisplayName("Category")> <Required()> Property PostCategory As String
    Property Comments As IList(Of Comment)

    'Post has collection of Tags
    <DisplayName("Tags (comma separated)")> Overridable Property PostTags As ICollection(Of Tag)
End Class


    Public Class Tag
    Dim _rdsqlconn As RDSQLConn

    <Key()> Property TagId As Int32
    Property PostId As Int32
    Property TagWord As String

    'Overridable property to access Post
    Overridable Property Post As Post

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Created the template Tags.vbhtml in the EditorTemplates folder and applied  to PostTags. the template has the textbox which is shown in the view.